# perl: printing new line instead in a single line

Tags: perl

I am new to perl. 
when i m trying to print the values of the array along with one variable in the while loop, 
the variable is printing in the new line.

```
while($line=<FH>)
{
    chomp($line);
    $tem = grep(/gooty/,$line);
    if($tem==1)
    {
        $Date=$date;
        @array=split(/\|/,$line);
        $sth = "INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES $array[1],$array[2],$date \n";
    }
}
print "$sth \n";
```

the output:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES alan ,777  
,2012-07-31
```

instead i want the output as :

```
INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES alan ,777,2012-07-31
```

in single line

Answer (score 5):

This is a common problem for new perl programmers.  Say

```
while (defined($line = <FH>))
{
    chomp $line; # Eliminate terminating newline if there
    ...
```

If the results are still not right, you may be trying to read a text file with MSDOS/Windows line endings using a version of Perl (like Cygwin) that doesn't handle them correctly.  This can cause `chomp` to malfunction.  You can work around the problem using this instead:

```
$line =~ s/[\r\n]+$//;
```

This cleans *all* end-of-line characters from the end of the line, no matter how many there are.,

Additional notes on your code: You'll save lots of trouble for yourself with `use strict;` and `use warnings;`, which will require variable declarations with `my` and `our`.  You don't need to call `grep`.  Just say `if ($line =~ /gooty/) {`.  If there is any chance of extra whitespace in your data, a better split pattern is `\s+\|\s+`. This will consume whitespace around the vertical bar field separators. In that case you also want to use

```
$line =~ s/\s+$//;
```

instead of `chomp $line`.  This will clean all whitespace from the end of line, which includes end-of-line characters.

Comment: `while(defined($line = <FH>))`

Comment: You're right, though in this case a blank line is an error, dropping out prematurely is maybe not such a bad outcome.

Comment: yeah, it is another Perl feature, that will not be implemented in this situation (maybe). it is for knowledge

Answer (score 1):

You have a newline at the end of `$line`. `chomp` it, before splitting it, to get the desired output.

```
chomp $line;
```

[`perldoc -f chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html)

Comment: I did that already, but it still printing in the new line. :(

Comment: Note I edited my answer to account for what is probably wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you don't want your elements of `@array` enclosed by whitespace characters. Then we should trim them before printing them.

```
my $line = <FH>;

my $date = '2012-07-31'; # or whatever

if($line =~ /gooty/)
{
    my @array = split /[|]/, $line;
    foreach (@array) {
      s/^\s+//; # removes leading  whitespaces
      s/\s+$//; # removes trailing whitespaces
    }
    print "INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES $array[1],$array[2],$date \n";
}
```

This should print the desired output.

But I cannot be sure until you show us the *input* you gave your code that produced the unexpected output. (Or could it be that you modify your `$sth` between the loop and the `print` statement? I see you appended two newlines?)

Btw: `use strict; use warnings`!

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest approach, instead of using `chomp`, is to remove all trailing whitespace from the end of the line

Start your loop with

```
$line =~ s/\s+\z//;
```