# Perl print() adding newline after loop iteration

Tags: perl, for-loop

I'm making Tic-Tac-Toe in Perl 5.24 and am working on displaying the winning move in a different color, so I'm iterating through each character in the board and using `print()` to show the characters to the screen.

The problem I'm having is that every time the `for` loop increments, `print()` adds a newline to each character.

I've used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11731939/6674014),
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11731938/6674014),
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11739565/6674014), and
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12757687/6674014) and there's still a newline, so it seems to me the issue is either with `print()` and/or how loops work in Perl.

Here's the entire project as requested:

```
use 5.24.0;
use warnings;
use strict;

use Win32::Console;

my $CONSOLE = Win32::Console->new( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );

my $attr = $CONSOLE->Attr();

$| = 1;

use constant { TRUE => 1, FALSE => 0 };

use subs qw(pause);

my $player     = "X";
my @usedXMoves = [];
my @usedOMoves = [];

my $xScore = 0;
my $oScore = 0;

my $winningMove = "";

my %indsToCheck = (
    Top    => [ 0,  2,  4 ],
    Bottom => [ 12, 14, 16 ],
    Left   => [ 0,  6,  12 ],
    Right  => [ 4,  10, 16 ],
    MidV   => [ 2,  8,  14 ],
    MidH   => [ 6,  8,  10 ],
    DiaTB  => [ 0,  8,  16 ],
    DiaBT  => [ 12, 8,  4 ]
);

main();

sub main {
    my ( $gameBoard, %boardInds ) = ResetBoard();

    DisplayBoardAndInds( $gameBoard, \%boardInds );

    my $res = -1;
    while ( TRUE ) {
        if ( -2 == $res ) {
            DisplayScores( TRUE );

            last;
        }
        elsif ( 1 == $res ) {

            # Update score first
            if   ( "X" eq $player ) { $xScore++; }
            else                    { $oScore++; }

            say "\n\nWe have a winner!\nWould you like to play again? (Y/N) ";
            my $again = <STDIN>;
            chomp $again;

            if ( "Y" eq uc( $again ) ) {
                ( $gameBoard, %boardInds ) = ResetBoard();
                $res = -1;

                DisplayScores();

                SwitchPlayer();
            }
            elsif ( "N" eq uc( $again ) ) {
                DisplayScores( TRUE );

                last;
            }
        }
        else {
            $res = ValidateAndApplyMove( GetInput( \%boardInds ), \$gameBoard );
        }

        DisplayBoardAndInds( $gameBoard, \%boardInds );
    }
}

sub pause {
    <STDIN>;
}

sub SetColor {
    $CONSOLE->Attr( shift );
}

sub ResetColor {
    $CONSOLE->Attr( $attr );
}

# Will display text in color
# in: Color, text
sub PrintInColor {
    SetColor( shift );

    $CONSOLE->Write( shift );

    ResetColor();
}

# Resets the gameboard and playable indicies
sub ResetBoard {
    my $gameBoard = "_|_|_\n_|_|_\n | | ";
    my %boardInds = (
        TL => 0,
        TM => 2,
        TR => 4,
        ML => 6,
        MM => 8,
        MR => 10,
        BL => 12,
        BM => 14,
        BR => 16
    );

    @usedXMoves = [];
    @usedOMoves = [];

    return ( $gameBoard, %boardInds );
}

# Displays the current board and usable moves
sub DisplayBoardAndInds {
    system( "cls" );

    my $board   = shift;
    my $refInds = shift;

    if ( "" ne $winningMove ) {
        my @winningInds = @{ $indsToCheck{$winningMove} };

        my $indInd  = 0;
        my $currInd = $winningInds[0];

        # TODO:
        # Figure out why new lines are being appended here

        use Data::Dumper;

        $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
        $CONSOLE->Write( Dumper $board);
        $CONSOLE->Write( Dumper $FG_RED);
        pause;

        for my $i ( 0 .. length( $board ) - 1 ) {

            if ( $i eq $currInd ) {
                PrintInColor( $FG_RED, substr( $board, $i, 1 ) );
                $indInd++;
                $currInd = $winningInds[$indInd];
            }
            else {
                $CONSOLE->Write( substr( $board, $i, 1 ) );

            }

            pause;
        }

        $CONSOLE->Write( "\n" );

        $winningMove = "";
    }
    else {
        say $board;
    }

    say "Current player = $player\n";

    # Sort by value (using reference)
    foreach my $k ( sort { $refInds->{$a} <=> $refInds->{$b} } keys( %$refInds ) ) {
        $CONSOLE->Write( "$k, " );
    }

    $CONSOLE->Write( "EXIT\n" );
}

sub DisplayScores {

    system( "cls" );

    my $final = shift;

    if   ( $final ) {
        say "Final scores:";
    }
    else            {
        say "Scores:";
    }

    say "X: $xScore";
    say "O: $oScore";

    if ( $final ) {
        say "\n\nThanks for playing!";
    }

    pause;
}

# Retrieves and validates input
sub GetInput {

    $CONSOLE->Write( "What move would you like to make? " );
    my $move = <STDIN>;
    chomp $move;    # <STDIN> returns with a newline
    $move = uc( $move );

    my $refInds = shift;

    my $ret = -1;

    if ( "exit" eq lc( $move ) ) {
        $ret = -2;
    }
    if ( exists $refInds->{$move} ) {
        $ret = $refInds->{$move};
        delete $refInds->{$move};
    }

    return $ret;
}

# Displays any error message
# If none, then applies the move to the board
sub ValidateAndApplyMove {

    my $move      = shift;
    my $gameBoard = shift;

    if ( -2 == $move ) {
        return -2;
    }
    elsif ( -1 == $move ) {
        say "\n\nInvalid move. Please try again.";
        pause;
    }
    else {
        my $tBoard = ${$gameBoard};
        my $len    = length( $tBoard );

        $tBoard = substr( $tBoard, 0, $move ) . $player . substr( $tBoard, $move + 1, $len );

        ${$gameBoard} = $tBoard;

        if ( "X" eq $player ) {
            push @usedXMoves, $move;
        }
        else {
            push @usedOMoves, $move;
        }

        if ( CheckWin() ) {
            return 1;
        }

        #SwitchPlayer();
    }

    return 0;
}

# Updates the current player
sub SwitchPlayer {
    if ( "X" eq $player ) {
        $player = "O";
    }
    else {
        $player = "X";
    }
}

# Checks current moves against winning conditions
sub CheckWin {

    my @moves = [];

    if ( "X" eq $player ) {
        @moves = @usedXMoves;
    }
    else {
        @moves = @usedOMoves;
    }

    return (
           GetRow( "Top", @moves )
        or GetRow( "MidH",   @moves )
        or GetRow( "Bottom", @moves )
        or GetRow( "Left",   @moves )
        or GetRow( "MidV",   @moves )
        or GetRow( "Right",  @moves )
        or GetRow( "DiaTB",  @moves )
        or GetRow( "DiaBT",  @moves )
    );
}

# Returns true if the passed in array contains all the values for a given row

sub GetRow {
    my $row   = shift;
    my @moves = @_;

    # Convert array to map
    my %moves = map { $_ => 1 } @moves;

    my @indsToCheck = @{ $indsToCheck{$row} };

    foreach ( @indsToCheck ) {
        if ( !exists( $moves{$_} ) ) {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    $winningMove = $row;

    return TRUE;
}
```

With a board of:

```
X|X|X
O|X|_
O|_|O
```

This outputs:

```
X  
|  
X  
|  
X  
...
```

So how do I print without newlines during a loop?

Comment: Needs more [mcve].

Comment: *"What do you mean "what prints the '|' characters"? print() does"* The point is that you haven't shown the *code* that prints those characters. You don't appear to have shown the part of your program where the problem lies. *"The entire project is only ~300 lines"* Then just post it all if you can't reduce the code to something small that still malfunctions.

Comment: Please add this directly before your `for` loop. `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print Dumper $board;` and report back with the result.

Comment: @Borodin The problem lies within the for loop. The if and elsif both have a call to print(), and during the same iteration, print() works as expected. I can print as much as I want and it will be on the same line. But when a full execution occurs and the loop starts over, new lines begin to show up when using print(), regardless of how much white space stripping I do.

Comment: `for(my $i = 0; $i < length($board); $i++)` is generally written as `for my $i ( 0 .. length($board) - 1 )`

Comment: @Borodin $VAR1 = "X|X|X\n_|_|_\n | | | ";

Comment: @Borodin Writing the loop like that didn't fix it

Comment: @Borodin I was typing that when you posted the dump code, so I didn't see it. I posted my result.

Comment: Can you leave that code in place and add `print Dumper $FG_RED;` please.

Comment: @Borodin $VAR1 = 4;

Comment: As far as I can tell from the documentation for `Win32::Console`, you should be using `$CONSOLE->Write(...)` instead of `print(...)`. Please try that.

Comment: @Borodin Nope. That didn't do it.

Comment: Have you replaced `print` everywhere?

Comment: @Borodin Yes. All of them have been replaced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update

Having seen your full code I know exactly what is happening

Your program has this loop

```
for my $i ( 0 .. length( $board ) - 1 ) {

    if ( $i eq $currInd ) {
        PrintInColor( $FG_RED, substr( $board, $i, 1 ) );
        $indInd++;
        $currInd = $winningInds[$indInd];
    }
    else {
        $CONSOLE->Write( substr( $board, $i, 1 ) );
    }

    pause;
}
```

where `pause` is

```
sub pause {
    <STDIN>;
}
```

which means you have to press *Return* to step through the loop. Each time you do that, a newline is echoed to the screen. Remove that `pause` and it will work

---

There's no reason why the code you show should be printing newlines unless you've added them yourself elsewhere

The best I can do for you is to post an example program that uses the string you say is in `$board` and displays it with the **X** characters in red. Note that `Attr()` doesn't *reset* the colour; you must set it back to white (or whatever) with `Attr($FG_WHITE)`

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Win32::Console;

my $c = Win32::Console->new(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

$c->Cls($FG_WHITE | $BG_BLACK);

my $board = "X|X|X\n_|_|_\n | | | ";

for my $ch ( split //, $board ) {

    if ( $ch eq 'X' ) {
        $c->Attr($FG_LIGHTRED);
        $c->Write($ch);
        $c->Attr($FG_WHITE);
    }
    else {
        $c->Write($ch);
    }
}
```

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd: What I've found so far in your code is that you have multiple calls to `say`, which are the same as `print`, as you have a `system("cls")` which should be `$CONSOLE->Cls($FG_WHITE | $BG_BLACK)`.

Comment: This example does work. Once I get it implemented into what I'm doing I'll give you the green check.

Comment: Weird. When I run your code it works fine, but when I compare ints instead of strings inside the loop, that's when it goes wrong. I added an outside counter and only changed the first if to check numbers and it no longer works. Then when I put it back it is fine again.

Comment: Oh my God. I figured it out. I was calling pause() every iteration, which calls <STDIN>. Removed that and it works great. Holy crap. Thank you for your patience. :)

Comment: I just wrote that in my answer. Just shows you mustn't be so certain where the fault is, and show your *real* code!

Comment: By the way, definitions like `my @usedXMoves = []` are wrong. That sets the array to contain a single element, which is a reference to an empty array. You can write `my @usedXMoves = ( )` if you must, but just `my @usedXMoves` is fine and more usual.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd: The same applies to the statements that are supposed to empty the arrays; `@usedXMoves = []` should be `@usedXMoves = ( )`

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd: Note particularly that, had you not remove that `pause` call in your original post, you would have been asked what it did straight away and would have got a much quicker answer.

Answer (score 1):

If `$board` doesn't contain any newlines, then you are claiming that `print` is appending newlines to what you tell it to print. By default, `print` doesn't append anything. If it's appending newlines, you must have set `$\ = "\n";` (possibly by using `-l`).

Comment: I know print() isn't supposed to append anything. That's why I'm so confused as to whether the problem is with print() or the loop itself, as it only adds a new line after each iteration. I'm not setting $\ anywhere, but what should it be?

Comment: By default, it's undef. /// If you execute `PrintInColor($FG_RED, "a"); PrintInColor($FG_RED, "b");`, you'll see them on the same line unless you did something you didn't show.

Comment: Yes. Printing one after the other works fine, even during the loop. It's only **after** the loop goes back to the top that there's an issue.

Comment: You are mistaken. The existence of the loop has nothing to do with this.

Comment: I had thought so. That's why I came here. I can't think of any reason the loop would cause this, but that's when it happens.

Comment: Object can be destroyed at the end of the loop pass, but there are no variables scoped to your loop. So again I say, you are mistaken. The existence of the loop has nothing to do with this. Please rediagnose the problem.